# Is this correct : "the bigger a dream is, the harder is to achieve."

Tags: grammar

I believe it's correct from a view of grammar, but is it clear?

Comment: Aren't you missing an "it"?

Comment: Do you mean:  The bigger a dream is, the harder is to achieve it?

Comment: no, "the harder it is to achieve it". See Dori's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not grammatical.

A more correct version would be:

> The bigger a dream is, the harder it is to achieve

But a version that sounds more natural to my ear is:

> The bigger the dream, the harder to achieve

Comment: +1 it's good that you put a better suggestion there too.

Comment: Your second example doesn't sound so natural to me, I would either say "The bigger the dream, the harder it is to achieve", or try and find a noun to mirror the "dream": "The bigger the dream, the harder the implementation" (though that doesn't sound great either...)

Comment: for some reason I actually find the original (fixed) version more natural than the proposed "more natural" one.

Comment: Your first version sounds the most standard to me — it’s the one I’d most expect to hear in everyday speech — but your second is very rhetorically effective to my ear: imaginative, so slightly unexpected, but completely natural nonetheless.

Comment: @PLL - Yep, you got it. In retrospect, I should have clarified one point: version 1 is better if it's just one sentence among many, while version 2 is better if it's being used as a title or statement on its own. It should have the same feeling as *The bigger they are, the harder they fall*.

Comment: I like the first suggestion better, but I don't like the word achieve. I suggest replacing "achieve" with "realize" (make the dream real) or "to make it happen".